# receiving empty value for the associate object when accessing the List in ajax (code-first EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, linq, entity-framework

I have a `Post` object and it has its associated `List<Comment>` and `Person` who made the post. When I retrieve the `Post` value in ajax, I get `List<Comment>` empty and I get `Person` with the correct value. Here is my code in web api controller that returns a single `Post` object:

```
 public Post GetPostWithFullDetails(int postId)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == postId)
                           .Include(p => p.Person)
                           .Include(p => p.CommentsAssociated)
                           .Include(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                           .Include(p => p.PostLikes).
                           AsNoTracking().ToList().Select(p => new Post
        {
            PostId = p.PostId,
            Title = p.Title,
            Content = p.Content,
            DatePosted = p.DatePosted,
            Person = p.Person,
            CommentsAssociated = p.CommentsAssociated,
            IsLikedByCurrentUser = p.PostLikes.Select(pl => pl.UserId).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            IsBookmarkedByCurrentUser = p.PostBookmarks.Select(pb => pb.BookmarkedBy).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            NoOfComments = p.CommentsAssociated.Count()
        }).First();

        return post;
    }
```

If I remove the part starting with `Select(p => new Post..` then I receive a valid CommentAssociated object as well (however, I need other properties such as `NoOfComments`) :

```
    public Post GetPostWithFullDetails(int postId)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        var post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == postId)
                           .Include(p => p.Person)
                           .Include(p => p.CommentsAssociated)
                           .Include(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                           .Include(p => p.PostLikes).
                           AsNoTracking().ToList().First();

        return post;
    }
```

And, here is the associated sections of the `Post` class:

```
 public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> CommentsAssociated { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Boolean IsLikedByCurrentUser { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Boolean IsBookmarkedByCurrentUser { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int NoOfComments { get; set; }

}
```

Also, when I try the following property definition for `CommentsAssociated`, I still get empty value, but then, I can access to _comments property that has the list of the comments. And, this makes me really confused! :

```
    public List<Comment> _comments;
    public List<Comment> CommentsAssociated {
        get { return _comments ?? (_comments = new List<Comment>()); }
        set { _comments = value; }
    }
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here, and solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

Here is the output for `CommentsAssociated` (has not values field) and `_comments` (has values field) :

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

Defining anonymous function also did not work, it still behaves the same.

```
 public dynamic GetPostWithFullDetails(int postId)
    {
        gEchoLuDBContext db = new gEchoLuDBContext();
        IEnumerable<dynamic> post = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostId == postId)
                           .Include(p => p.Person)
                           .Include(p => p.CommentsAssociated)
                           .Include(p => p.PostBookmarks)
                           .Include(p => p.PostLikes).
                           AsNoTracking().ToList().Select(p => new
        {
            PostId = p.PostId,
            Title = p.Title,
            Content = p.Content,
            DatePosted = p.DatePosted,
            Person = p.Person,
            CommentsAssociated = p.CommentsAssociated,
            IsLikedByCurrentUser = p.PostLikes.Select(pl => pl.UserId).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            IsBookmarkedByCurrentUser = p.PostBookmarks.Select(pb => pb.BookmarkedBy).Contains(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            NoOfComments = p.CommentsAssociated.Count()
        });


        var postToIncreaseViewCount = db.Posts.Single(p => p.PostId == postId);
        postToIncreaseViewCount.Views = postToIncreaseViewCount.Views + 1;
        db.SaveChanges();

        var returnpost = post.First();
        return returnpost;
    }
```

Comment: When you say "empty value", do you mean an empty list or null? Also, is `AssociatedComments` a typo? There is no `AssociatedComments` prop in your snippets.

Comment: I bet this line `get { return _comments ?? (_comments = new List<Comment>()); }` is causing the problem

Comment: @dellywheel but why? `_comments` is available but `CommentsAssociated` not although it should return `_comments`.

Comment: Have you tried taking `new List<Comment>()` out of the get? and setting new List elsewhere

Comment: @dellywheel I tried this `public List<Comment> _comments = new List<Comment>();
        public List<Comment> CommentsAssociated
        {
            get { return _comments; }
            set { _comments = value; }
        }` but the situation did not change. I have valid `_comments` but `CommentsAssociated` is empty.

Comment: this is strange. Maybe try and project to anonymous type eg `Select new { CommentedAssosiated = p.CommentsAssosiated .. ` instead of new Post

Comment: @dellywheel yes, I changed. It still behaves the same way. Please see the update above.